# nextjs serverside post response return curropted zip file from external api but the api request works fine with postman

Tags: node.js, api, next.js, axios, xlsx

so I have an API with an endpoint that returns an xlsx file on post request

when I call that API from nextjs server side API it returns a corrupted zip file

but when I call it directly through postman it returns the expected xlsx file.

the call to the API from nextns looks like this:

```js
axios.post(`${process.env.API_URI}`, formData, {
        headers: {
          ...formData.getHeaders(),
        },
         responseType:"blob"
      }).then(response => {
         res.status(200).send(response.data)
        tmpObj.removeCallback()
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        tmpObj.removeCallback()
      })
```

is there a proper way to receive the xlsx file in nextjs API ... Nodejs

update:

eventually I had to set the Content-Type in axios header and the responseType in axios config object

```js
axios.post(`${process.env.API_URI}`, formData, {
          headers: {
            ...formData.getHeaders(),
            'Content-Type': 'blob',
            
          },
          responseType:"arraybuffer"
        }).then(response => {
          //createthe buffer in the frontend const buffer = Buffer.from(response.data, 'base64');
          

           res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
          // res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;filename=SheetJSNode.xlsx')
          res.status(200).send(response.data)
        }).catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
        })
```